# Prove that $I$ (an integral) is differentiable and find its derivative at $x_0$

Tags: analysis

I have to consider the functional $I: C[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by: $$I(x) = \int_a^b x(t)\ dt$$ The derivative at $x_0$, according to my understanding, should be given by: $(DI)(x_0) = x_0(b) - x_0(a)$ (which is bounded since $x_0$ takes values on a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$) right? So I'm left to show that this claim can satisfy the definition of a derivative as a linear map: $$\forall \epsilon > 0,\ \exists \delta > 0 \ \text{s.t.} \ \|x - x_0\| < \delta \implies \dfrac{\|I(x) - I(x_0) - (x_0(b) - x_0(a))\|}{\|x - x_0\|} < \epsilon$$ The only thing is I'm now confused about how to proceed (or whether I've used the correct approach so far). Could I start like so: $$\|I(x) - I(x_0) - (x_0(b) - x_0(a))\| \leq \|(b-a)\|x - x_0\|_{\infty} - (x_0(b) - x_0(a))\|$$ Or is this completely wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the Fréchet derivative, i.e. given $f:X\to Y$ from one Banach space to another, the Fréchet derivative $Df$, is defined to be the (necessarily unique) $linear$ transformaton $A:X\to Y$ such that

$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{\left \| f(x)-f(x_0)-A(x-x_0) \right \|}{\left \| x-x_0 \right \|}=0$

Now, since $I$ itself is linear then trivally $DI=I$:

$\frac{\vert I(x)-I(x_0)-I(x-x_0)\vert } {\left \| x-x_0 \right \|}=\frac{\vert I(x)-I(x_0)-I(x)+I(x_0)\vert } {\left \| x-x_0 \right \|}=0$.

Comment: I thought that originally but then how can the derivative of an integral be the integral itself?

Comment: This follows from the definition. If you think about it, it's even true for $X=Y=\mathbb R$ because in that case the only linear tranformations are of the form $A(x)=ax$, so that when you use the more general formula you see that the number $a$ is just $f'(x_0)$.